# Error when installing npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting this message when running `npm install -g @angular/cli`:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4

My Node is **v8.10.0**, Npm version is **3.5.2** and my operating system is **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

Could anybody help ?

Thanks

Comment: Try `npm install --no-optional`...

Answer (score 1):

You need a higher version of both Node and npm. From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli):

> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node
>   8.9 or higher, together with NPM 5.5.1 or higher.

As mentioned by @DaltonCézane [`npm install --no-optional`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) might also help you:

> The `--no-optional` argument will prevent optional dependencies from
>   being installed.